# Running JIRA and Confluence in local machine

Tags: mysql, jira, confluence

I have JIRA (port: 8080) and Confluence (port: 8090) services running on my local machine. Both these services are accessing two different databases running on one MySQL instance. MySQL service instance is running on port number 3306.

### The problem I'm facing is that if I start JIRA, Confluence gets disconnected and vise-versa.

More description as requested: I log into Confluence, it works fine and I can create spaces and pages and everything. Then I start JIRA service (just start not log in). Then I refresh Confluence page I automatically get logged out and cannot log in back. I try to log in into JIRA and I get access. Same thing happens if I start with JIRA first and start with Confluence then.

Can anyone tell me how to solve this?

Comment: Are Jira and Confluence running on different ports? I have Jira running on port 8080 and Confluence on port 8090. If they use the same port, they will bump each other.

Comment: No they are running on different port like yours.

Comment: Are users stored in two different databases, or are they sharing the same one?

Comment: While setting up JIRA, I have linked it with a separate database. So I believe user account will be saved in  separate databases?

Comment: So when you say "Confluence gets disconnected", what happens exactly? Does the user get logged out? Doyou have a database error?

Comment: So, when I run JIRA service the admin user gets disconnected in Confluence. If I try to log in again while JIRA service running it gives me an error, saying password is correct until I switch off JIRA service and again rerun confluence.  Same thing is with jira while running along side with confluence.

Comment: Do you have Confluence configured to use JIRA for centralized user management?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that JIRA and Confluence override each other cookies if they share the URL. Everything is explained (including a solution):

https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/user-is-constantly-logged-out-of-jira-192872663.html

Cheers,

Gorka

Comment: This is not the case here. I have kept different users in the 2 services but still one service is suppressing other service from working.

Answer (score -1):

Jira and Confluence always use different databases to store content and configurations, but they can share users. For example, you can set your users in Jira and connect Confluence to that user base; this way, you don't have to re-create users again in Confluence.

You seem to have a user base conflict. I suggest you check your configuration in Confluence Admin under General Configuration - User Directories. If you have "Remote JIRA Directory" under Directory Name (or vice-versa in Jira's admin), then both applications share the same user base. If you created local users despite that, they might be conflicting with each other.

Comment: This is not the case here.